# Why aren't more of the mutants having their powers restored?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

If you look at the answer supplied to this question: [How did Magneto get his powers back after M-Day?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14428/1148) you see that Magneto's powers were restored through the High Evolutionary's *extremely dangerous technological procedure*.

This suggests to me two things.

1. The X-Gene is still a factor for mutants, even though they can't *access* their abilities.
2. A lot of mutants would probably be wanting to get their abilities back.

While there are some who are probably happy to be "normal", I suspect there is a fairly large population of mutants who would be willing to take the same risks as Magneto to restore their abilities. I would also think that Magneto would be one of the people pushing to restore those powers to the mutant population.

So why aren't more mutants gaining their powers back through this process?

Comment: I'd assume cause of the extremely dangerous technological procedure part lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the [High Evolutionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Evolutionary) would love to have such a willing group of subjects (he is a bit amoral in his quest for knowledge) the technology and capability to restore access to a mutants genetic legacy would be difficult to find or apply to the entire world at one time. The other reason I suspect no one has made an effort to restore everyone's access to their genetic potential is it partially resolves a problem that the Marvel Universe had, which was FAR too many (dangerous) mutants in the general populace.

The High Evolutionary did mention the ingredients included parts of a [Celestial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_%28comics%29) (one of the first, most powerful species in the Marvel Universe, believed to have seeded the Earth with life, and having altered the human genome for the potential of mutant powers and development) and genetic technology of the first order. Other sites that could possess that ability might be the laboratories of [Dr. Victor Von Doom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr_Doom), [Dr. Reed Richards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Fantastic), and to a lesser extent, SHIELD, Advanced Idea Mechanics, Hydra and other select super-intelligent geneticists such as [Arnim Zola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnim_Zola), [Apocalypse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocalypse_%28comics%29) and [Mister Sinister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr_Sinister).

He also mentions the process is extremely dangerous and did not expect there to be a high rate of survival. Only mutants whose powers mattered more than their lives, or clearly had powers that were potentially Alpha or Omega level would be willing to take the risk. Magneto was an example of a person who met both criteria.

And while this list appears to be a long one, The High Evolutionary is likely to be one of the most sophisticated and capable geneticists/mutant-power biological scientists on Earth.

Comment: +1 great answer.  Note also that almost all of the scientists capable of pulling this off are *dangerous nutcases* that you *really* wouldn't want to trust your life and genome to if you can help it.

Comment: Amen, brother. Amoral sociopaths might be just a bit kind when describing them...